# Can inequality that holds for the product of array also holds for sum?

Tags: inequality

Given $\{a_i\}_{i=1}^n$ and ${b_i}_{i=1}^n$, $0< a_i \le 1$, $0< b_i\leq 1$.
if $\prod_{i=1}^n a_i \ge \prod_{i=1}^n b_i$
Can we prove that $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i \ge \sum_{i=1}^n b_i$ ?

Answer (score 1):

No. A simple counter-example is
$$0.2 \cdot 0.6 = 0.12 > 0.08 = 0.1 \cdot 0.8 \, ,$$
but $$0.2 + 0.6 = 0.8 < 0.9 = 0.1 + 0.8 \, .$$